# Resizing childs but with minimum height for child1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create resizable divs using jQuery draggable works perfectly but there is an issue as it's not recognizing where to stop..

This is what I have done so far,

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('.resizeDiv').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: '#container1',
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var $child1 = $("#child1");
        if ($child1.outerHeight() > 50) {
            var height = ui.offset.top - 10;
            $child1.height(height);
            var totalHeight = $("#container1").height();
            var preHeight = totalHeight - height;
            $("#child2").height(preHeight);
        }
    },
});
});
```

```css
#container1 {
width: 300px;
height: 240px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#child1 {
height:100px;
min-height:50px; 
width:100%;
background-color:red;
}
#child2 {
height:100px;
width:100%;
background-color:green;
}
.resizeDiv {
border: 1px dashed #CCC;
background-color: #FFFFEE;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container1">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div class="resizeDiv"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/749/

**I want dragging to stop when child1 reaches it's minimum height**

Comment: Where are you indicating the `min-height`? is it `if ($child1.outerHeight() > 25) {` ?

Comment: Sorry there was some issue, I fixed my question now, main problem still there :(

Comment: still not very clear what you are trying to acheive. do you want it to stop you, but allow you then to go the other way?

Comment: @BG101 yes, as you can see it is stopping but increasing height of child2, so I want to stop it EXACTLY when child1 reached it's minimum height

Answer (score 1):

In the else condition inside `drag` function, call `preventDefault` so that as soon as condition fails, it should stop dragging further

Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/751/

However noticed a bug that once it reaches minimum height of child1, it can't be dragged in opposite direction, looks like condition needs to be updated

EDIT: updated if condition, now you can drag to either side and dragging stops when either child1 or child2 reaches min height
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/752/

Comment: Thanks but it still not works properly, I want it to moveable but with in containment, at the moment it stops and then unless you grap handler again, it stays like that....